# Which Font type will show the difference O(alphabet) and 0(zero)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts

In c# i use the **arial,times new roman,Curlz MT** font types **it will dispaly the O(alphabet) AND 0(ZERO) As A same** ,which means string a="**OT02O**" its show like this.maxium no differenct between them. when i try to display in arial or something else it will display **OTO2O**.So i need to know which font will give the maximum difference between O and 0?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest **Consolas** is better to show the differences between O(alphabet) and 0(zero)

Answer (score 1):

Have you [googled](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=font%20that%20differenciate%20zero%20and%20alphabet%20O&oq=font%20that%20differenciate%20zero%20and%20alphabet%20O&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about this, Check the following links that i figure out to be relevent to your question:
[Zero, Slashed Zero,  Letter "O", Alt-0216 Ø and Phi Φ](http://www.k8zt.com/zero.html)
[Finding the Best Programmer's Font](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/12/6/11739/5249)

> '0', 'o' and 'O' are easily distinguished

Use the slashed 0 to solve this problem.